# Double letters when checking differences between two lists

Tags: python

How do I make sure this code checks for duplicated letters? (In this case, I  only want to print if there is a second `"b"` in `list2.)

Here is my code:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "b"]
list2 = ["a","b"]

if all(elem in list1 for elem in list2):
 print("they have all the same letters")
```

Here is the output I want:

```
they have all the same letters
```

Comment: Is `set.issubset`/`set.issuperset` what you need?

Comment: @EricJin It needs to account for duplicate letters, so I don't think this would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the number of occurrences of each letter, and then check whether all the occurrences are the same between each list:

```py
from collections import Counter

if Counter(list1) == Counter(list2):
    print("they have all the same letters")
```

Comment: Elegant & performant too.   even better `this` doesn't care about the `ordering`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sorted(your_list)`:

```py
if sorted(list1) == sorted(list2):
    print("they have all the same letters")
```

It works without any imports